# How to assign a dynamic value to the label helper in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am working on a Asp.net MVC 2.0 web application. In my form , i have  non editable fields , so i wanted to display them as labels rather than textboxes.

I am strongly binding my model with view. So, i need to associate this label with one of the fields in model.

This is what i am trying to do:

```
 <%=html.LabelFor(model=>model.changedby)%>

<%=html.DisplayFor(model=>model.changedby,XYZ)%>
```

But, it is displaying nothing..Please help

**Updated2:**

What basically i am trying to do is a add operation. i have a create view and that view has a form.

I am strongly binding this view with model.So , that i can directly associate form fields with the model Properties.

Ex:

```
<label> Name</label> <%=Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.name)
```

So, what ever i type into the textbox , it will be stored in m.name in the model.

If the text entered is "Avinash" , then m.name gives value "Avinash"

I think i am correct upto this extent:

Similarly..

I have a field which is readonly , the user can not change the value of it.

```
<label>Changed On</label>  <label> DateTime.Now </label>
```

How to bind m.ChangedOn with the labels values(DateTme.Now)

so that it will result in m.Changedon as DateTime.now

**Updated3:**

This is what i am writing..

```
                    <td >
                        <%=Html.LabelFor(Model=>Model.CreatedOn) %>:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%=Html.HiddenFor(Model=>Model.CreatedOn) %>
                    </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You no need to wrap with `<label>`, since MVC `LabelFor` will automatically create those html tags for you

So change this

```
<label>
  <%=html.LabelFor(model=>model.changedby)%>
</label>
```

to

```
  <%= Html.LabelFor(model=>model.changedby) %>
```

**Update:**

If you want to send the data to the server while you post your form, make sure you have a data in a form fields. Only form fields like `input,select,textarea` are posted to server and not display tag value like `label, span, div, etc`

Still if you need to post the label value, you can use hidden with it

```
<%= Html.LabelFor(model=>model.changedby) %>
<%= Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.changedby) %>
```

If you have both, your hidden field will posted to server, which contains the same value

**Controller code**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
MyviewModel model=new MyviewModel();
model.ChangedOn=DateTime.Now;
return View(model);
}

For Save

public ActionResult Save(MyviewModel model)
{

 model.ChangedOn; // this property will show you hidden value
 //If you need current time, since the rendered time was old. Its good to assign like below
 //model.ChangedOn=DateTime.Now
}
```

Comment: @Murali..Updated my question

Comment: @Murali.how to i assign XYZ value to model.changedby..Sorry seems to me lot of confusion..I understood that to post data to server we should be using only form fields..

Comment: If you edit `model.changedby` label value using javascript, then you need to update the `hiddenfield` also. Give some `id` to hidden field and set the value using `$('#hiddenid').val($('#label-id').text());`

Comment: @Murali..Iam not editing model rather i am creating a new model and sending it to controller.

Comment: @Avinash, Please update you code. I dont understand what you are actually trying to implement

Comment: @Avinash, While your render `<%= Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.changedOn) %>` you will be having the current time stored in hidden  field. This will be posted to the server when you click submit. Your model also will hook the `changedOn` from this hiddenfield. The hidden field is nothing but `input type='hidden'`

Comment: @Murali..yes understood now..but where are we metioning that value DateTime.Now

Comment: @Avinash, check out the updated answer. Not sure you understand MVC

Comment: @Thanks Murali..I understood little better now..I was able to post that value to server..After you posting that controller code, i understood . I really thank for patient answering..you might have got easily frustrated beacuse of my questions :)

Comment: @Avinash, You are welcome. Nothing like that. Without understanding the clear context , its difficult to answer :). check out channel9.msdn.com Scott Hanselmen's ASP.Net MVC video. You can easily understand about MVC :)

Comment: @Murali..Sure i will check it out. Each feature of MVC is really amazing me day by day..

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<%= Html.DisplayFor(model => model.changedby) %>
```